# refresh div content with json result from js function

Tags: jquery, json

First to describe my scenario. On my page I have div with id showImage. Bellow that div there are few thumb. images which I want to display in larger in showImage div, without refresh page ofcourse.
So here's what I have up to this moment.
Generated html for every image is

```
<a href="/Property/GetImage/7">
  <img id="7" class="details" width="100" height="100" src="/Property/GetImage/7" alt="">
</a>
```

I'm fetching image id and pass it to my controller which will return me an image
(maybe I dont need this, cause I already have this image on same page, but I dont know how to use it)
to continue, controller will return me an image which I need to show with larger dimensions in showImage div placeholder.
Here's my code

```
function ShowLargeImage(imageId) {
        $.ajax({
            url: ('/Home/GetImage'),
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({ id: imageId }),

            success: function (result) { 
                //need to pass result(image)to my div
            },
        });
    }

    function onPopUp() {
        $(".details").click(function (event) {
            var imageId = (this.id);
            ShowLargeImage(imageId);
        });
    }
```

**Question is:
How can I call from js my showImage div, for example. showImage.Show(result);
Is this possible?**

Comment: is result an `<img src="..." />` tag? or?

Comment: I dont know how pass result to my div?

Comment: @andreas result is File, not image path

Comment: not sure what you mean by File, could you paste the result string?

Comment: Instead of passing the larger image back in the AJAX call, why not just retrieve the path and set the src property of the image tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have the image and want to show that in another div you could do

```
    $(".details").click(function (event) {
        //clone the clicked image
        var clone = $(this).clone();
        //change the dimensions
        clone.height("150px").width("150px");
        //place it in the placeholder           
        $('div#placeholder').html(clone);
    });
```

Comment: is it possible to get cloned image in resulted div with different dimensions ?

Comment: @user313378 yes of course, i've updated my answer, just modify the clone :)

Comment: one last thing, now when I'm have all thumb images how can on page load set first image to be cloned and show automatically on targer div. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for jQuery's [`html()` function.](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

But then again, simply returning the image file's source won't help you.

What you'd want to do (if you absolutely *must* return the source as such, which is a bad idea for too many reasons to list them all here) is to base64-encode the image along these lines:

```
function base64_encode_image ($imagefile) {
    $imgtype = array('jpg', 'gif', 'png');
    $filename = file_exists($imagefile) ? htmlentities($imagefile) : die('Image file name does not exist');
    $filetype = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if (in_array($filetype, $imgtype)){
        $imgbinary = fread(fopen($filename, "r"), filesize($filename));
    } else {
        die ('Invalid image type, jpg, gif, and png is only allowed');
    }
    return 'data:image/' . $filetype . ';base64,' . base64_encode($imgbinary);
}
```

Your AJAX success callback then would look like this:

```
success: function (large_img_src) { 
    $('#showImage').html('<img src="' + large_img_src + '"/>');
}
```

---

A much cleaner version, as mentioned by Chris Gessler, would be to fetch the large image's URL only:

```
function ShowLargeImage(imageId) {
    $.ajax({
        url: ('/Home/GetImage'),
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ id: imageId }),

        success: function (large_img_url) { 
            $('#showImage').html('<img src="' + large_img_url + '"/>');
        }, 
    });
}
```